# Can the T-800 see in night vision?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

Apparently, when it was in the cop compound, it was able to turn off the lights and pretty much nail every cop on first shot. Pretty neat that the T-800 series could see in night vision, probably something that Kyle Reese should have mentioned!

Comment: Valorum: It should state "Does the T-800 see in night vision? I edited it. I guess I was thinking more about the second movie than the first while writing this.

Comment: Rand: The other question, also written by me, is more general. I did not care whether or not he could see in night vision or not. In actuality, there was never a dark scene in the second movie, from what I had seen, that would have wanted me to know this. Then again, I wonder if the T-1000 COULD SEE in the dark now that we are on the topic.

Comment: I think that the fact that he turns off the lights as part of his shooting spree is a pretty clear indication that he has an advantage in the dark over human vision. I am not sure what about that is confusing. It seems to me that the real question you are asking is *why did Kyle Reese not mention it,* although that seems more like a complaint about Kyle Reese than an objective question.

Comment: Rebel: So a T-800 and T-1000 are the same thing? WHAT?!

Comment: @Rebel-Scum I looked at the "duplicate" question's answer. It talks about the way the T-1000 is able to mimic eyes as a machine made of nanobots. That, of course, has nothing to do with the T-800. Moreover, the actual question here is about the way the T-800 sees, whereas the "duplicate" is about the way the T-1000 sees. Those are different questions by definition. Can you please give some reason why you believe the two questions are duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

The T-800 has an infrared vision mode, as seen in this picture from [this FAQ](http://www.jamescamerononline.com/TheTerminatorFAQ.htm) (emphasis mine)

[image: T-800 infrared mode]

> The Terminator's optical sensors can sample an extended range of visible frequencies, including infrared (which can allow it to see heated bodies in total darkness). This information is then displayed on a 40,000 bit digitized display. Concussion-proof lenses protects its eyes, which are capable of moving independently. When using both eyes to track two different targets moving in different directions, depth perception is created artificially by creating a computer-generated off-angle ghost image. 800 series is capable of motion tracking, search modes, facial identification and recognition and has extensive vision enhancement capabilities including long range zoom (can snap-magnify an image by around x15), motion analysis **and night vision**. He can also calculate temperatures and weights.

The [novelization](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel)) says

> During that time it would certainly have opportunities, like now, for economy mode, where power was cut to 40 percent of nominal function. The optical system switched to infrared only.

This indicates he has a normal optical mode. While this comes later, [Cameron](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Cameron) from the Terminator series, seems to prefer normal optical mode.

Comment: Also in T2 when it's driving in the dark.

Comment: You might as well add the rest of the quote from the FAQ; ***The Terminator's optical sensors can sample an extended range of visible frequencies, including infrared (which can allow it to see heated bodies in total darkness). This information is then displayed on a 40,000 bit digitized display. Concussion-proof lenses protects its eyes, which are capable of moving independently. When using both eyes to track two different targets moving in different directions, depth perception is created artificially by creating a computer-generated off-angle ghost image...***

Comment: ***...800 series is capable of motion tracking, search modes, facial identification and recognition and has extensive vision enhancement capabilities including long range zoom (can snap-magnify an image by around x15), motion analysis and night vision. He can also calculate temperatures and weights.***

Comment: Also if you're going to quote from the novelisation, it's a good idea to check whether the novelisation actually says the thing you're quoting

Comment: Valorum: Unless he is paraphrasing. Also, it would not hurt to cite the quoted material in APA format :D